# How to measure segment length and branch angle

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I am trying to measure segment length and branch angle or bifurcation angle between each pair of segments.

My image after thinning looks like this:

[image]

```
 i = Import@"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68983831/thinned.png";
 dat = ImageData[i]; 
 i1 = Image[dat[[34 ;; 242, 28 ;; 213]]]
 g = MorphologicalGraph[i1, EdgeWeight -> Automatic]
```

thus output looks like:

[image]

Comment: The image you uploaded does not give that graph if you plug it in `MorphologicalGraph`. Please give original image.

Comment: There is a range of possible interpretations of the "bifurcation angle," depending on how closely one focuses in on each vertex. At high magnification, all angles must be multiples of 45 degrees, for instance. At the lowest magnification we might elect to draw straight line segments between vertices and use the angles at which they meet, even though these angles might differ greatly from the correct local angles. One idea that allows some control is to intersect a small disk around each vertex with the image and use the *relative areas of the black sectors* in the disk to estimate the angles.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**-------------- Length --------------**

Imagine you got an image called **img** that gives you your morphological graph. Visualize approximately where your vertices are in terms of the pixel coordinates:

```
g = MorphologicalGraph[img, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  PlotRangePadding -> 15, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, 
  VertexSize -> .4, VertexStyle -> Yellow, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Get vertex coordinates:

```
vc = AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates]
```

> VertexCoordinates -> {{107.5, 139.5}, {87.5, 105.5}, {131.5, 115.5}, 
>      {112.5, 87.5}, {55.5, 86.5}, {27.5, 99.5}, {115.5, 67.5}, {59.5, 11.5}}

Realize relationships between vertex coordinates and vertex labels:

```
vcl = Sort[Rule @@@ Transpose[{VertexList[g], vc[[2]]}]]
```

> {1 -> {107.5, 139.5}, 2 -> {131.5, 115.5}, 3 -> {87.5, 105.5}, 4 -> {27.5, 99.5}, 
>      5 -> {112.5, 87.5},  6 -> {55.5, 86.5}, 7 -> {115.5, 67.5}, 8 -> {59.5, 11.5}}

Get legthes of edges in terms of pixel coordinates:

```
el = {#, EuclideanDistance[vcl[[#1, 2]], vcl[[#2, 2]]] & @@ #} & /@ EdgeList[g]
```

> {{1 [UndirectedEdge] 3, 39.4462}, {2 [UndirectedEdge] 5, 
>        33.8378}, {3 [UndirectedEdge] 5, 30.8058}, {3 [UndirectedEdge] 6, 
>        37.2156}, {4 [UndirectedEdge] 6, 30.8707}, {5 [UndirectedEdge] 7, 
>        20.2237}, {6 [UndirectedEdge] 8, 75.1066}}

```
Grid[el, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Visualize as labels:

```
elg = Graph[EdgeList[g], vc, EdgeLabels -> Rule @@@ el, 
  GraphStyle -> "ThickEdge", VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Bold, 18], PlotRangePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

**-------------- Angle --------------**

Define some functions. Turn a single edge into a pair of its vertex coordinates:

```
ctp[x_] := {#[[1, 2]], #[[2, 2]]} &@(vcl[[#]] & /@ (x))
```

Slope based on 2 points:

```
sl[{a_, b_}] := Divide @@ Reverse[a - b]
```

Angle based on 2 slopes:

```
ang[{a_, b_}] := ArcTan[Abs[(sl[ctp@a] - sl[ctp@b])/(1 + sl[ctp@a] sl[ctp@b])]]
```

According to the 1st picture in my post your branching vertexes are {6,3,5}, so here you go with angles in degrees (where 1st column is triple of vertices labeling the angle):

```
data = {Union[{#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]]}], 
     180 - 180/Pi ang[#]} & /@ Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ 
     EdgeList /@ (NeighborhoodGraph[g, #] & /@ {6, 3, 5}), 1];

Grid[data, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Compute centers of triangles and place the angle labels stylized in blue:

```
la[x_] := Text[Style[x[[2]], Blue, Italic], Mean[vcl[[#, 2]] & /@ x[[1]]]]

Show[Graphics[la /@ data], elg]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

```
thin = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/me0gY.jpg";
thin = Dilation[thin, 3];
g = MorphologicalGraph[thin, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the vertex `|5|`

```
vc = PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ Sort@VertexList[g];
vcOff = # - vc[[5]] & /@ vc;
vectors = Extract[vcOff, List /@ Cases[EdgeList[g], _[x_, 5] | _[5, x_] -> x]];
Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ vectors, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the angles can be obtained by

```
Mod[Subtract[#[[1]], #[[2]]], 2 Pi] & /@ Partition[ArcTan @@@ 
                                  Join[vectors, vectors[[1 ;; 1]]], 2, 1]
```